# MetroFramework MenuStrip Now Showing in ToolBox

Tags: c#

[image]

I installed packages for MetroFramework but there's no MetroMenuStrip and the other tools.

When I search the web I see too much examples about MetroMenuStrip. But nobody has any problem like mine.

I tried with all these package codes :

```
Install-Package Winform.Metroframework
Install-Package MetroFramework
Install-Package MetroModernUI
Install-Package MetroFramework.Design
```

Answer (score 0):

They dont have the MetroMenuStrip control, You can check the source code 
[here](https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui/tree/master/MetroFramework/Controls) .May be the control has been removed due to some bugs and issues.